# Variables validation (name and IP address) in bash

Tags: bash, validation, variables

In the header of my bash script, I have to ask for the user name and his IP address.

I need to validate entries in this way:

- The user name have to be stored in a `name` variable, having his space replaced by underscores. For sample if user hit `"Albert Smith"`, I have to store `"Albert_Smith"` into my variable `name`.
- For the ip address, I need to know if the ip address is consistent with the format.
  If the format is not good, I must report the error and prompt the user to enter a good ip address to continue the operation.

I know that i need to use "read", but i don't know to realize my short script (replace and verify).
Thank in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your entries will be line based (ie. the name will be the first line and the IP the second). You can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

read name    
while [[ ! "$name" =~ '[A-Za-z ]' ]]; do
    read -p "Wrong name format. Re-enter: " name
done

name="${name// /_}"

read ip
while [[ ! "$ip" =~ '^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9]|[0-9]{1,2})[.]){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9]|[0-9]{1,2})$' ]]; do
    read -p "Not an IP. Re-enter: " ip
done
```

The IP regex is rather complex, but it can be decomposed as:

1. After the start of the string, there must be three groups of "octet" followed by periods, then followed by another "octet" and the end of the string
2. Octet is either

   1. 250-255,
   2. 200-249
   3. 100-199 (including 000-099, with the explicit 0s before the number)
   4. One or two digits (ie. 0-99)

The loop forms will negate `!` the result of the `grep`, so it will continue looping while the `grep` command fails. We use `printf` in order to pass the variable into `grep`. The `-E` flag on the second `grep` allows the use of extended regular expressions, which include the `|` OR operator, `()` grouping and `{}` repetitions.

Hope this helps a little =)

Comment: Tips: Use `grep -q` instead of redirecting to /dev/null.  Use `read -p` instead of running an extra printf.  Use [substring replacement](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) (`${var/pat/repl}`) instead of piping things through tiny sed scripts. And use bash's `[[` operator instead of `[`, so that you can use fun things like the regex comparison operator (`=~`) instead of piping through grep at all.

Comment: Thanks! I think it got a better by becomin bash-only =)

Answer (score 7):

Yet another way. Bash only:

```
#!/bin/bash

read name
name=${name// /_}

read ip
if [[ "$ip" =~ ^([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})$ ]]
then
    for (( i=1; i<${#BASH_REMATCH[@]}; ++i ))
    do
      (( ${BASH_REMATCH[$i]} <= 255 )) || { echo "bad ip" >&2; exit 1; }
    done
else
      echo "bad ip" >&2
      exit 1;
fi

echo "name:$name"
echo "ip:$ip"
```

Answer (score 5):

not exactly the answer to the question, but for those who love "one liners", an IP validating regex:

```
[[ "$IP" =~ ^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$ ]] && echo "valid" || echo "invalid"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the first part with `tr`, and the second part with `grep` and `awk`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Enter a name:"
read FULL_NAME

FULL_NAME_REPLACED="$(echo $FULL_NAME | tr ' ' _)"
echo $FULL_NAME_REPLACED

echo "Enter an IP address:"
read IP_ADDRESS

if echo "$IP_ADDRESS" | egrep -E '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
then
    # Then the format looks right - check that each octect is less
    # than or equal to 255:
    VALID_IP_ADDRESS="$(echo $IP_ADDRESS | awk -F'.' '$1 <=255 && $2 <= 255 && $3 <= 255 && $4 <= 255')"
    if [ -z "$VALID_IP_ADDRESS" ]
    then
        echo "The IP address wasn't valid; octets must be less than 256"
    else
        echo "The IP address was valid"
    fi
else
    echo "The IP address was malformed"
fi
```

If found the `awk` expression used there in [this thread](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/36144-ip-address-validation-function.html).  This is an improvement on using `grep` or `sed` alone, in that it will also reject octects that are greater than 255, such as `400.400.400.400`.

Answer (score 0):

```
read name
name=`echo $name|tr ' ' _`

read ip
stat=1
if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
    OIFS=$IFS
    IFS='.'
    ip=($ip)
    IFS=$OIFS
    [[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255 \
        && ${ip[2]} -le 255 && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]]
    stat=$?
fi
```